# How to update pjsip version in CSipSimple

Tags: android, c, pjsip, csip-simple

I am using CSipSimple code for my project since last one year, and unfortunately the development of the CSipSimple has stop and also support.

I want to update pjsip version into code. I have also tried to plug latest code of [pjsip](http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk/). But facing lots of issues in compiling CSipSimple with latest code of pjsip using **'make'** command. I have replaced latest pjsip code/directory with  **CSipSimple -> jni -> pjsip -> source** directory but no luck.

**Build Environment**

- System OS : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Version of pjsip : 2.5.5 [download](http://www.pjsip.org/download.htm)
- Compiling source for android architecture: armeabi, armeabi-v7a,
  mips, x86
- Steps for build CSipSimple: [Steps](https://sourceforge.net/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild/)

If someone had already done with this or having any idea for my error then please help me it would be really appreciated.

```
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : pjsipjni <= pjsua_jni_addons.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : pjsipjni <= reason_parser.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : pjsipjni <= zrtp_android.c
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: pjsipjni <= zrtp_android_callback.cpp
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : pjsipjni <= pjsip_opus_sdp_rewriter.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : pjsipjni <= ringback_tone.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : pjsipjni <= android_logger.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : pjsipjni <= audio_codecs.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : pjsipjni <= csipsimple_codecs_utils.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : pj_amr_stagefright_codec <= stagefright_amr.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : pjsip <= sip_config.c
jni/pjsip/android_toolchain/pjsip/../../sources/pjsip/src/pjsip/sip_config.c:57:5: error: initializer element is not constant
     },
     ^
jni/pjsip/android_toolchain/pjsip/../../sources/pjsip/src/pjsip/sip_config.c:57:5: error: (near initialization for 'pjsip_sip_cfg_var.tcp.keep_alive_interval')
jni/pjsip/android_toolchain/pjsip/../../sources/pjsip/src/pjsip/sip_config.c:62:5: error: initializer element is not constant
     }
     ^
jni/pjsip/android_toolchain/pjsip/../../sources/pjsip/src/pjsip/sip_config.c:62:5: error: (near initialization for 'pjsip_sip_cfg_var.tls.keep_alive_interval')
make[1]: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/pjsip/src/pjsip/sip_config.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
rm jni/swig-glue/android_toolchain/../.pjsua.i
make[1]: Leaving directory `/backup/CSipSimple-trunk/CSipSimple'
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'libraries' failed
make: *** [libraries] Error 2
```

Comment: got any clue for updated pjsip version ?

Comment: I haven't found any thing yet but now pjsip has launch new version 2.6 I will look into it and try, if you have any solution then reply

Comment: do you have any guidelines/clue about how to add latest pjsip library into CsipSimple ?